# Can't read csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I'm trying to read a csv file. In the code below, the for loop is not entered and no exception is thrown:

```
csvfile = r"C:\Development\input-data\Locations.csv"
try:
    with open(csvfile, 'r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|') 
        for row in reader:
            #print ("row: " + str(row)) 
            print (', '.join(row))
except IOError:
    print ("IOError: " + csvFile)
    sys.exit()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
The error is 2 parts. First, as @bernie suggests, I had overwritten the csvfile with my code. Second, change the code as @KarenClark shows.

Comment: You're overwriting `csvfile`...

Comment: This would happen if the csv file is empty.

Comment: As @bernie says, you are overwriting the csvfile variable. I'm not sure that won't work, but it's really a "bad idea" (tm). Also, what is "cvsFile". Lastly, please post the exact format of your csv file (e.g. the first line, or a typical line).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the csv file inside the "with open" section, like this:

```
try:
    with open(r'C:\Development\input-data\Locations.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|') 
        for row in reader:
            print (', '.join(row))
except IOError:
    print ("IOError: " + csvFile)
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: And yes, I know mentioning the csvfile value inside the loop isn't Pythonic BUT the goal was to see if altering the location of the variable helped. The other commenter was right to say that csvfile was being overwritten with the new variable - if the above works, that is proven.

Answer (score 1):

i tried to read csv file using for loop and if else condition .
seems too big
but it is working for me...
try it.

```
import sys
f1 =open("csv_file.csv")
def splitter(f1):
   f2 = f1.readlines()
   check = 0
   check1 = 0
   x =""
   y =""
   temp=[]
   for row in f2:
      if row.find('"')!= -1:
        for i in row:
            if i == '"':
                check = check+1
                if (check)%2 == 0:
                    temp.append(x)
                    x=""
                continue
            if (check)%2 != 0:
                x = x+i
                continue
            if i == ',':
                check1= check1+1
                if (check1)>= 2:
                    if y=="":
                        continue
                    temp.append(y)
                    y=""
                continue
            if i=='\n':
                y = y+i
                temp.append(y)
                y=""
                continue
            if (check1)>=1:
                y = y+i
                continue
            if i=="":
                continue
        for s in temp:
            print s
        temp=[]
    else:
        z= row.split(',')
        for a in z:
            print a

def main(argv):
  splitter(f1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  try:
    main(sys.argv)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

`